# ArrayList Underlying Array Cost

Tags: java, amortized-analysis

I was recently reading up on the ArrayList from Java. From my understanding, when an ArrayList reaches its capacity it calls its resize method and creates a new underlying array that's *double* the size of the original. This way insertion can be regarded as O(n) due to this case, but on average it's still O(1). However I'm confused on the reason behind it specifically being increased to twice the size. 
Would it be better to have it increased 3x the original capacity?

Comment: You've been reading old documentation.  The growth function no longer simply doubles the default.  But that does not affect the cost discussions below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What's important is that the capacity is increased by a constant factor. It doesn't matter what that factor is: 1.5 is as good as 3. The amortized cost will be O(1) - constant time. Different factors lead to different constants though.

If you do the math taking the factor into account, the amortized time cost is O(f/(f-1)) where f is the factor. If doubling has time cost of 2, tripling has time cost 1.5.

Increasing capacity by a large factor leads to fewer resize operations but more wasted space. You have to find a balance: is reducing execution time by 25% worth a 50% increase in storage overhead?

Answer (score 0):

For an answer to the effect of the resizing factor on ammortized cost and asymptotic complexity, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60896436/14955).

Let me attack this from a different, more practical angle.

The designers of the standard library have to find a good default behaviour that works for a very wide range of general workloads. Occasionally, after much consideration and benchmarking, they change these things (see implementation details evolution for HashMap or String). There is always a trade-off and you cannot get it absolutely right for every usecase.

If you find that the default behaviour does not work for you, you as the application developer have the ability and obligation to tweak the defaults.

In the case at hand, if you already know that your ArrayList is going to need to grow beyond the default initial capacity, you can tell the constructor to pre-allocate a larger one. And you can later also call `ensureCapacity` and `trimToSize` to adjust it.

Answer (score 0):

Remember that the `O` notation only consideres the scaling behaviour up to a constant. While a 3x increase would decrease the runtime, the scaling behaviour would still be linear O(1). It can not get better if the cost for inserting is 1. So the amortized cost can never be better than O(1) for inserting.

If you look at the proofs, you will find out that the cost per element for scaling with 2x is 3 and for scaling with 3x it is 2.5, both being constant, so O(1).

The average cost for a scaling factor s is: `(2s - 1) / (s - 1)` and it the cost is O(1) for any scaling factor s > 1. Even a very small scaling factor, like 1.1, while having a cost per element of 12, would still have an amortized insertion cost of O(1).